# Cannot boot after Ubuntu installation on Win 10 disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I've installed Ubuntu 19.10 in a partition on by SSD alongside Windows 10. The installation went fine until I tried to reboot.

The PC now just loops and keeps restarting. I've been into the BIOS and tried changing the boot priority for all three options but it still wont boot either into Ubuntu or Windows.

Also tried disabling secure boot and CSM but it makes no diff.

Mainboard is an ASUS TUF B450. Drive is a Kingston 500GB SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Just open grub Loader and fix Currupted files may be Helpful

on startup just press continuously shift key
select root mode (Terminal Window)

fsck /dev/sda1 2 3 ...!  Etc   select as per your partition list.

Done.

Comment: There is no startup, just a black screen for a few seconds and the machine reboots into this same cycle. No menus, no Grub loader, nothing.